# Does anyone know how to fix "[Error] expected primary-expression before '.' token" problem?

Tags: c++, function, struct, void

This is the code that I made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct Account {
  string username;
  string password;
};

struct Schedule{
    char place[100];
    char time[100];
};

bool validatePassword(const string& password) {
  const regex pattern("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$");
  return regex_match(password, pattern);
}

void createAccount() {
  Account newAccount;
  string password;

  // Get user input for username
  cout << "Enter Username: ";
  getline(cin, newAccount.username);

  do {
    // Get user input for password with validation
    cout << "Enter Password (minimum 8 characters with at least 1 number and 1 special symbol): ";
    getline(cin, password);
  } while (!validatePassword(password));

  newAccount.password = password;

  // Open file for writing account in append mode
  ofstream outfile("accounts.txt", ios::app);

  if (outfile.is_open()) {
    outfile << newAccount.username << endl;
    outfile << newAccount.password << endl;
    outfile.close();
    cout << "Account created successfully!" << endl;
  } else {
    cerr << "Error opening file for account storage!" << endl;
  }
}

void Tickets(){
    int ticket, pw;
    
    reset:
    cout << "Enter your Password: ";
    cin >> pw;
    if (pw == Account.password){
        cout << "How many tickets will you order?: ";
        cin >> ticket;
        
        cout << "Thank you for ordering!"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid Password. Try Again!" << endl;
        goto reset;
        system ("pause");
    }
}

void Book(){
    Schedule location[100] ={   
        {"San Mateo", "5:00"},
        {"Sta. Lucia", "5:30"},
        {"Santolan", "5:35"},
        {"Cubao", "4:00"},
        {"Philcoa", "4:30"},
    };
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        cout << location[i].place << endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    int choice;
    
    do{
        cout << "=== MKD Bus Ticket System ===" << endl;
        cout << "1. Create Account" << endl;
        cout << "2. Order Ticket" << endl;
        cout << "3. Book Schedule" << endl;
        cout << "4. View Schedule" << endl;
        cout << "5. Display Account" << endl;
        cout << "6. EXit" << endl;
        
        cin >> choice;
        cin.ignore();
        
        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            cout << "Account Creation screen" << endl;
            createAccount ();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Order Tickets" << endl;
            Tickets ();
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Booking" << endl;
            Book ();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Schedule Viewer" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Account Information" << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
            break;

        }
    }while (choice != 6);
}
```

Its not complete yet, but I want to point something out that is bugging me. At line 56, the error where primary expression is expected before '.' token keeps popping up. Is there a way to fix this problem?

I tried adding newAccount in the Tickets() function. but it wasn't working. I expected it to work but it didn't fixed the error.

Comment: `Account.password` is invalid. You need an object for the `.` operator, not a class name. Think about your design. Which account are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

> At line 56, the error where primary expression is expected before '.' token keeps popping up. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Line 56 is this:

> ```
>     if (pw == Account.password){
> ```

`Account` is the name of a *type*, and `password` is an *instance* field of that type.  Therefore `Account.password` does not identify an object that you can compare to `pw`.  Presumably, you want to compare to the `password` member of some existing `Account` instance, but it's not clear which one.  Even your `createAccount()` function does not provide an `Account` instance that survives completion of that function.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, @johann1220: "Presumably, you want to compare to the password member of some existing Account instance."  But it's not a *simple* fix, because your program has design problems, as I touched on already.  You need to think about where it will store account data, and how that data will be made accessible where it is needed.